# How to use principal component analysis (PCA) to answer eda questions and how to use principal component for linear regression?

Tags: r, linear-regression, pca

[image: backpain data]

```
backpainX <- backpain_data[7:10]
backpain.pca <- prcomp(backpainX, center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)
summary(backpain.pca)
```

[image]

```
backpain.pca$rotation
```

[image: PCs]

1. How can I perform PCA to combine the four pain variables (neck, thoracic, lumbar, sacral) and take the first PC as the response?
2. How can I use the PC as the response for regression?
3. How can I use PCA for EDA (exploratory data analysis)?

Questions I want to answer:

1. How does activity level affect pain levels for thoracic, lumbar, sacral, and neck?
2. Does height affect pain levels for thoracic, lumbar, sacral, and neck?
3. Does age affect pain levels for thoracic, lumbar, sacral, and neck?

Comment: You can access the single scores with `backpain.pca$x` and use it for a regression. The question is if you really want to/should. You show that the first component only explains 43% of the variance. Therefore it is not clear how reflective of "general pain" this might be. To assess the PCA it is always a good idea to check with `pairs()` and plot the different data points. This might also help you to assess whether using it for regression is a useful approach.